# How to plot many linegraphs on one page with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

In gnuplot, I want to plot many line graph in one window. I drew graph with `multiplot` but the label names are not displayed properly, label1 and label2 are printed over each other.

How can I solve this issue? Also can I save a figure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always prefer to make scripts for gnuplot over typing in shell, doing so, you don't need multiplot. Instead, you can run a script like this

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

set terminal png crop size 1600,600;
set output "figure.png";

plot x, \
     x*x, \
     x*x*x,
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unaware of `gnuplot's` "multiplot" command.  It looks like you might be able to do what you want with judicious use of `set origin`, but I'd advise doing `help multiplot` and carefully reading what it has to say.

As far as "saving a figure" goes, I can interpret that one of two ways:

1. Save the entire `gnuplot` configuration at that moment, including
   the last "plot" command. You'd do `save "somefile.load"` at the
   `gnuplot>` prompt.  At some later time, you would do `load
   "somefile.load"` at the `gnuplot>` prompt to regenerate the whole
   thing on screen.
2. Produce a file containing the figure.  The file is in some image format like GIF, JPEG, or some printable format like PostScript.  Do `help set terminal` to see how to set the terminal. I'll assume you want PostScript, but you can pick format later:

   gnuplot>set term postscript

   gnuplot> set out "plot.ps"

   gnuplot> replot

   gnuplot> set term X11

You should have a printable PostScript version of your plot in file "plot.ps"  To get a GIF image, you'd say  `set term gif`, `set out "something.gif"`, and `replot`.  Sometimes, an output file will be zero bytes until you do `set term x11` (or whatever).